# Declare a class as the parameters for an OData action in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I like the way in WebAPI how you just put a defined model as the parameter in a method of a controller. I'm switching to OData and every example I've found of working with a data structure is by defining it in the modelBuilder

```
var action = builder.Action("MyAction").ReturnsCollection<int>();
action.Parameter<int>("ProgramId");
action.Parameter<int>("BrandId");
action.Parameter<int>("StoreId");
action.Parameter<OperationStatus>("Status");
```

and then in the controller you must manually get those values from the ODataParameter dictionary. I find this tedious. 
Also in the WebAPI way you can catch errors at compile time or by VisualStudio intelisense, and do validations with annotations.

Are there other ways to pass the parameters to an action? Something more like the WebAPI "perks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a custom DTO as a parameter for an `OdataAction`.
For example the code for registering would be like:

```
var action = builder.Action("MyAction");
action.Parameter<OperationStatus>("Status");
action.ReturnsCollection<int>("Results");
```

And the Json payload for the request would be like:

```
{
    "Status": {
        "Property1":"value",
        "Property2":"value"
    }
}
```

Action declaration in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("MyAction")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyAction(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    OperationStatus status;
    if (!parameters.TryGetValue("Status",out status))
    {
        return BadRequest("Missing parameter Status");
    }
}
```

Comment: So, simple. Although it still uses a dictionary, having the DTO is enough for me.
Also, using an out parameter needs to be assigned to an object and then be casted to OperationStatus.